# Estimote: Beacon Manager Ranging Questions

Tags: listener, scanning, estimote

The following is code being used in an app I am working on. The app will try to detect an Estimote beacon and then output in Android notifications the distance of the beacon. The issue I am running into is that the notification is being sent every second, when it should be sent every 1/10th of a second - from setting the foreground scan period. Changing the advertising interval of the beacon didn't seem to have much of an effect either. Is there something I am missing with this?

```
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(100,0);
    beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(100,0);


    beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, List<Beacon> beacons) {

            if (beacons.size() < 1) {

                return;
            }
            count++;
            String distance = "" + getDistance(beacons.get(0).getRssi(), beacons.get(0).getMeasuredPower());
            String beaconName = beacons.get(0).getName();
            showNotification(count + " Name + Distance", beaconName + ": " + distance);
        }

    });
```

Comment: With these settings, it actually should be called every 1/10th of a second. Maybe the notification itself gets throttled? Can you add some logging to ensure the `onBeaconsDiscovered` method itself is called every second?

Comment: Try and set the scan period to 110. An offset might help you to see most signals.